# Is there a way to pass a string to html javascript with command line?

Tags: javascript, html, string, command-line

I'm a beginner! I need something like this:

```
C:\MyHtmlPage.html "string_that_I_need_to_pass_to_the_javascript_code_inside_MyHtmlPage"
```

and put the "string_that_I_need_to_pass_to_the_javascript_code_inside_MyHtmlPage" inside:

```
var externalstring
```

Is there something similar to do that?
Thank you!

EDIT:

I found the way!
Inside DOS command line I write:

```
start firefox "file:///C:/MyHtmPage.html?externalstring=string_that_I_need_to_pass_to_the_javascript_code_inside_MyHtmlPage"
```

And in javascript I add this (http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/):

```
var externalstring = getUrlVars()["externalstring"];
alert(externalstring);

function getUrlVars() {
 var vars = {};
 var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, 
 function(m,key,value) {
     vars[key] = value;
 });
 return vars;
}
```

Thank you all for advices! =)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query parameter like this:

```
C:\MyHtmlPage.html?parm=string_that_I_need_to_pass_to_the_javascript_code_inside_MyHtmlPage
```

Then, in your page javascript, you can use `window.location.search` to retrieve the parm=xxxx piece and parse out the xxx if you want.  This format allows you to pass multiple different parameters if you want.  This is the generic way that you embed multiple parameters into a URL. They can then be parsed out by either javascript in the page or by the server if the URL comes from a web server.

Answer (score 1):

No, but if you are loading it in a browser you can use a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

Like this:

```
<a href="file:///C:/MyHtmPage.html#string_that_I_need_to_pass_to_the_javascript_code_inside_MyHtmlPage">CLICKY</a>
```

and then in javascript:

```
console.log(window.location.hash);
```